# Output voltages for HW-131

Tags: power-supply

I recently bought an electronics set which came with a breadboard power module, the HW-131. To test it, I connected it to my handphone charger, which should give me around 5 V DC. When I measured the output voltages of the power module using my multimeter, which were stated to be 3.3 V and 5 V, I instead obtained 2.6 V and 3.5 V.

I am wondering why I am not able to obtain the stated output DC voltages. I suspect the problem lies either with the internal circuitry of the power module or that my phone charger does not provide 5 V.

Any opinions on this?

Comment: You have a problem and we cannot help you without proper information. Since you measured the output voltages of the power module measure the output of the phone charger, also model number and links help. I will take a SWAG and say the power module needs at least 7 volts to operate properly as it contains linear regulators that will have a voltage drop. The odds are that the 3.3V regulator is fed by the 5V. From your measurements that should be about right.

Comment: @Gil My phone charger is just a regular Android phone charger. Most sources on Internet say that its output should be 5 +/- 0.25 V. Actually, how to measure the output of the phone charger? I'm really new to this. The phone charger has a USB port which I connect the charging cable to. Do I need to dismantle the phone charger?

Comment: If your HW-131 looks like this: [(link)](https://www.flyrobo.in/image/cache/catalog/mini-power-supply-module-hw-131-breadboard-power-module/mini-power-supply-module-hw-131-breadboard-power-module1-550x550.jpg) then you will need around 6.5V on the input to get regulation.

Comment: @TanYongBoon The HW 131 requires an input voltage of at least +6.5VDC and no more than +12VDC. The only reason it can accept USB is that the newer USB ports can engage in a "dialog" to set their voltage up to about +20 VDC, in some cases. So if the USB port supports it then the HW 131 can request a voltage it can use. Your phone charger just doesn't cut it.

Comment: Do not make the adapter. For a few sheckles you can get a charger that would work and will match the barrel connector. Anything greater then 1A would be good, preferably 2A. Ask your buddies they may give you one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested out @ErikR's and @jonk's comment with two power supplies,

- First one with 5V and I was getting same OP's results (that's why I came across to this question)
- Second one with 12V and 1A and I was getting 4.99V and 3.27V when using the bridge.

Seems like using a higher voltage PSU to deal with the voltage drop from the regulators will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

It is better to power the module with a 9v battery using the barrel connector.